# How to loop through each row in a repeating table using SharePoint Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I have an InfoPath form published to a SharePoint library and I have created a workflow that gets values from some of the fields in form and inserts them into a SharePoint List.

Now, in the form I also have a repeating table and when I try to get value (using workflows) of repeating table that has more than one row then it only return me the value of first row.

I want to iterate through repeating table to get value of each field within it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2013 workflow, or 2010?

Comment: Hi, I am using SharePoint 2013 and also SharePoint Workflow 2013. Thanks.